# How to store data of different applications in same local MySQL instance if both applications have multi-DB architecture?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

**Application 1:** Suppose I have a **Twitter** like application. Hence I need to use multiple databases/schema (suppose one to store user info, suppose one for user logging purpose, etc)

**Application 2:** Suppose I have a **blog** with logically separated DBs needed ( suppose one to store user info, suppose one for user logging purpose, etc ).

How to use **same MySQL instance** as the datastore for both. I mean, since each has multiple similar DBs , there are chances of getting confused with names of databases or tables unless I keep long names like **twitter_users** and **blog_users**.
Any effective solution within MySQL?

Comment: Can I use different ports as a solution?
How feasible is it wrt to taking backup etc?

Comment: as I know, no you can't. With different mysql instance you can do it.

Comment: @Msfvtp : Different MySQl instance- will different port in same local machine count ?

Comment: yes it need different port number

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try that.

Comment: You can put the tables in the same physical instance of MySQL in separate logical [databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-use.html).  Create a twitter database for the twitter tables and a blog database for the blog tables.  If you want, you can create a common database for tables that are used by more than one application.  All of these logical databases reside in the same physical MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

a other way is to use MaxScale as DB Proxy. There is rewrite Engine. There you can configure a rewrite for schema name for one application. The benefit is that you can use a single MySQL/MariaDB instance and configure the hole memory for it.